# Mysql : is the auto increment highest value always the most recent?

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I have a database with tables using InnoDB and an auto increment field as primary key. I'm wondering if I can rely on the fact that the highest value of a field using `auto_increment` is always the most recent.

I didn't find anything clear enaugh on this point.

Comment: Because rows can be deleted, NO. Even though the `auto_increment` is a continuous counter, some entries may be deleted, and you might find a value lower that what the current `auto_increment` might be. For example, say you insert 10 records, the `auto_increment` will be at 10. If someone ran a delete query to remove records for that column are greater than 1, your max query would only find 1, not 10. However, after the next insert query, the `auto_increment` value will be 11, not 2. See the proposed answer about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, if it might be related to your question.

Comment: My question was probably confusing or I maybe didn't get exactly what you are trying to explain. In fact, my question is about a `select`statement. So I implied that if I select the highest value of an `auto_increment` field, would I always have the most rectent entry ?

Comment: No, because of the delete factor, and the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is only relative immediately after an INSERT query.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. What does the delete factor implies here ? I mean, if I delete some entries, the highest existing value is still the most recent one no ?

Comment: You know, you can test this aspect yourself. Create a new table, add a few entries so that the `id` column (that is set as `auto_increment`) to have values from, say, 1 through 5 (or however many you prefer). Then delete a few entries, say, greater than 1, and see what you get when you select the max of the `id` column. You will **NOT** get the max of the `auto_increment` value, but only the max of what exists in the table for the `id` column.

Comment: I'm really wondering if my question is as confusing. I'm just looking for a pretty simple thing. I know all what you are saying and I want to select among exting values and be sure that a given value is always more recent than a lower one. So this is my question in fact

Comment: ...Not confusing to me, I believe that you are making more of the "simple thing" situation that is known. **You are never guaranteed** what the max of an `auto_increment` column might be, because of delete factors and other insert operations as would be typical in a single (or even multi-user) environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question, while looking for answer for similar question and I believe there is some confusion about this question - so to answer:  **can I rely on the fact that the highest value of a field using auto_increment is always the most recent**

according to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60295/why-does-auto-increment-jumps-by-more-than-the-number-of-rows-inserted
*(The only guarantees from an auto_increment column (or IDENTITY in MSSQL, and the other names the concept goes by) is that each value will be unique and never smaller than a previous one: so you can rely on the values for ordering but you can not rely on them not to have gaps.)*

Yes, unless you update auto-generated value manually.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. In case you insert a value and delete it, then max valu will not be the most recent one.

I suggest that you should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after you insert something.

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0).

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I forgot to specify that it's for a select statement.

Comment: Yeah, no problem, you can use it with SELECT also. Like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: Well I meant wihtout any INSERT, just a SELECT statement. I would use MAX instead.

Comment: You can use this without depending on any INSERT. FYI `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is a built in function in mysql. And using this function does not depend on any kind of INSERT.

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried it just to see and I had an empty array returned as expected. Btw, it's not the purpose of my question.

Comment: In short, the answer to your question is: No, you cannot rely on highest value of a field.

Comment: I appreciate your help but this kind of answer doesn't really make progress things. Can you give more explanations or cite a soure ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151669/discussion-between-ayushya-and-user3292788).